# Laplacian $\Delta u$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

The Laplacian $\Delta u$ in spherical coordinates is  $$\Delta u=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\rho^2}+\frac{2}{\rho}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\rho}+\frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\phi^2}+\frac{\cot\phi}{\rho^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\phi}+\frac{1}{\rho^2\sin^2\phi}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\theta^2}$$
 The way\tag[1](http://math.gmu.edu/~tlim/LaplaceSphericalCoord.pdf) I proved this is a bit tricky. I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this, e.g. using vectors or matrices , so the formula can be produced in a Computer Algebra System.

Answer (score 3):

Now I see a more straightforward way to convert $u_x\cos\theta+u_y\sin\theta$. From $$\left[\begin{array}{l}u_\rho\\u_\phi\\u_\theta\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{lll}\sin\phi\cos\theta& \sin\phi\sin\theta& \cos\phi\\\rho\cos\phi\cos\theta&\rho\cos\phi\sin\theta&-\rho\sin\phi\\-\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta&\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta&0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}u_x\\u_y\\u_z\end{array}\right]$$
 take the inverse of the matrix, using CAS, to get
 $$\left[\begin{array}{l}u_x\\u_y\\u_z\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{lll}\sin\phi\cos\theta& \frac{1}{\rho}\cos\phi\cos\theta& -\frac{\sin\theta}{\rho\sin\phi}\\\sin\phi\sin\theta&\frac{1}{\rho}\cos\phi\sin\theta&\frac{\cos\theta}{\rho\sin\phi}\\\cos\phi&-\frac{\sin\phi}{\rho}&0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}u_\rho\\u_\phi\\u_\theta\end{array}\right]$$
 from which we see that $u_x\cos\theta+u_y\sin\theta=u_\rho\sin\phi+\frac{1}{\rho}u_\phi\cos\phi $.